# TableGenerator don't working

Tags: php, database

I'm not sure about why isn't working my code. I've searched for help but I don't get any result.

The problem is that I don't get a full table with all the contents that it must print. The objective is to print a table with my timetable using a database.

Here you have an image of the current result:
[image: Current result]

However, I want to get the full table.

```
<?php

Class TBG {

    /*
     * #####################################################################################
     * ##################### Partes de Librerías Importantes ###############################
     * #####################################################################################
     */

    private static function initialCheck($param1, $param2, $param3) {

        if(!isset($param1) || !isset($param2) || !isset($param3)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
    private static function executeQuery($mysqli_table_name, $connection, $rown){

        if(self::initialCheck($mysqli_table_name, $connection, $rown)){
            return;
        }

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $mysqli_table_name WHERE id = $rown";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

        return $result;
    }
    private static function checkEmptyTable($result){

        if(self::initialCheck(" ", $result, " ")){
            return;
        }

        if($result -> num_rows === 0){
            echo "<center><h4>Esta tabla no ha sido a&uacute;n generada.</h4></center>";
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }

    /*
     * #####################################################################################
     * ################################ Librerías ##########################################
     * #####################################################################################
     */

    ///////////////////////////////////

    private static function getAmountOfRows($result){

        if(self::initialCheck(" ", $result, " ")){
            return;
        }

        return $row_max = $result->num_rows;

    }

    private static function getAssociated($result){

        if(self::initialCheck(" ", $result, " ")){
            return;
        }

        return $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    }

    ///////////////////////////////////

    private static function timeStart($row){

        if(self::initialCheck(" ", $row, " ")){
            return;
        }

        switch (strlen($row["time_start"])) {
            case 4:
                return $time_start = substr($row["time_start"], 0, -2).":".substr($row["time_start"], 2, 0);
            case 3:
                return $time_start = "0".substr($row["time_start"], 0, -2).":".substr($row["time_start"], 1, 0);
            case 2:
                return $time_start = "00:".$row["time_start"];
            case 1:
                switch ($row["time_start"]) {
                    case 0:
                        return $time_start = "00:00";
                    default:
                        return $time_start = "00:0".$row["time_start"];
                }
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
    private static function timeEnd($row){

        if(self::initialCheck(" ", $row, " ")){
            return;
        }

        switch (strlen($row["time_end"])) {
            case 4:
                return $time_end = substr($row["time_end"], 0, -2).":".substr($row["time_end"], 2, 0);
            case 3:
                return $time_end = "0".substr($row["time_end"], 0, -2).":".substr($row["time_end"], 1, 0);
            case 2:
                return $time_end = "00:".$row["time_end"];
            case 1:
                switch ($row["time_end"]) {
                    case 0:
                        return $time_end = "00:00";
                    default:
                        return $time_end = "00:0".$row["time_end"];
                }
            default:
                break;
        }

    } 

    ///////////////////////////////////

    /*
     * #####################################################################################
     * ############################ Partes Importantes #####################################
     * #####################################################################################
     */

    private static function generateTableHeader(){

        echo "<table class=\"global-tables-table\">";
        echo "  <tr>";
        echo "    <th>Tiempo</th>";
        echo "    <th>Lunes</th>";
        echo "    <th>Martes</th>";
        echo "    <th>Mi&eacute;rcoles</th>";
        echo "    <th>Jueves</th>";
        echo "    <th>Viernes</th>";
        echo "    <th>S&aacute;bado</th>";
        echo "    <th>Domingo</th>";
        echo "  </tr>";

    }
    private static function generateTableBody($row, $time_start, $time_end){

        if(self::initialCheck($row, $time_start, $time_end)){
            return;
        }

        echo "  <tr>";
        echo "    <td>".$time_start." - ".$time_end."</td>";
        echo "    <td>".$row["monday"]."</td>";
        echo "    <td>".$row["tuesday"]."</td>";
        echo "    <td>".$row["wednesday"]."</td>";
        echo "    <td>".$row["thursday"]."</td>";
        echo "    <td>".$row["friday"]."</td>";
        echo "    <td>".$row["saturday"]."</td>";
        echo "    <td>".$row["sunday"]."</td>";
        echo "  </tr>";



    }
    private static function generateTableFooter(){
        echo "</table>";
    }

    public static function generateTable($mysqli_table_name, $connection) {

        if(self::initialCheck($mysqli_table_name, $connection, " ")){
            return;
        }

        if(self::checkEmptyTable(self::executeQuery($mysqli_table_name, $connection, 0))){
            return;
        }

        self::generateTableHeader();
        for ($i = 0; $i < self::getAmountOfRows(self::executeQuery($mysqli_table_name, $connection, 0)); $i++) {
            self::generateTableBody(self::getAssociated(self::executeQuery($mysqli_table_name, $connection, $i)),
                    self::timeStart(self::getAssociated(self::executeQuery($mysqli_table_name, $connection, $i))),
                    self::timeEnd(self::getAssociated(self::executeQuery($mysqli_table_name, $connection, $i))));
        }
        self::generateTableFooter();

    }

}
```

Comment: The displayed message means "This table has not yet been generated".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call your class like this:

```
TBG::generateTable('table_name', new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'cdcol'));
```

It will execute the function `checkEmtpyTable()` with the result of the SQL Query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = 0
```

This will result in the check to fail and display the message.
I do not think that this code makes much sense. If you auto increment the id, it will start with 1, and if you do not there is not much sense to count one entry.

Please show us your database table with some entries. Did you write this class btw?

**Edit:**

Change the function `execute_query()` like that and you will get a bit further:

```
private static function executeQuery($mysqli_table_name, $connection, $rown){

    if(self::initialCheck($mysqli_table_name, $connection, $rown)){
        return;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $mysqli_table_name";
    if ($rown != 0) {
        $sql .= " WHERE id = $rown";
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: As you can see there is no row with the id 0.